# How to prove conditional independence properties

Tags: probability, independence

Currently, I am trying to figure out how to prove two properties of conditional independence.

1) P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)P(B|C)

2) P(A|B,C) = P(A|C)

(P(C) > 0)

As far as I use the first property, I could prove the second as follows:

$$P(A|B,C) = \dfrac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)} = \dfrac{P(A|C)P(B|C)}{P(B|C)} = P(A|C)$$

Then, how could I prove the first one?!

Comment: You *don't* prove the first one.  That is not a property of conditional independence. It is the *definition*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to prove.   It is not a property, it is a **definition**.   Events $A$ and $B$ are *defined* as being conditionally independent when given event $C$, if and only if their joint conditional probability when given event $C$ does equal the product of their conditional probabilities given $C$.

$$A\perp B\mid C ~\iff~ \mathsf P(A,B\mid C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)\;\mathsf P(B\mid C)$$